# View how a Dask dataframe is distributed across workers

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

Maybe it is because I am relatively new, but I can't seem to find the answer to this one.

After a `DataFrame.persist()` call, is there a easy way to see how much of that dataframe is stored on each individual worker?

Answer (score 2):

You need two functions:

- [futures_of](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/api.html#distributed.futures_of) to return the set futures holding results on the cluster
- [who_has](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/api.html#distributed.Client.who_has) to tell you where each piece is.

This should do it, operating on the dataframe returned by `persist()`.

```
client.who_has(futures_of(df))
```

Note, that immediately after calling `persist()`, the pieces of dataframe will start to be given to workers to process, but it may take some time for the whole persisting operation to complete; so there will be pieces that are not on any worker initially.

You can also have a look at the dashboard, which has links to the individual worker dashboards, which can list all of the data they hold.